# I'm Trying to Create a search field

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a search field in `PHP` and `HTML`. My code is not showing any error message, however it doesn't echo anything. My search page comes up blank.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  require './includes/databaseHandler.php';

  if(isset($_POST['submit-search'])){
    $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['search']);
    $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['location']);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM business WHERE BusinessName LIKE '%$search%' OR Address LIKE '%$search%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $QueryResult = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if($QueryResult > 0){
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $url = $row['BusinessName']."<br/>";
        echo "<a href='Businesspage.php?id={$row['id']}'>" . $url . "</a>";
        echo $row['Address']."<br/>";
        echo $row['Phone']."<br/> <hr>";
      }
    }else{
      echo "There are no result matching your search";
    }
  }
?>
```

And my HTML code from the search form:

```
<form action="searchindex.php" method="POST">
  <input id="form-control" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="What are you looking for?" name="search"><i id="form-control" class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <input id="form-control" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Jabi, Abuja?" name="location">
  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit-search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: you have unaccepted my answer. why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit-search">
```

It needs to be:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="submit-search">
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. It should be only type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a name tag into button section, which you forget.
and button `type` should be `submit` not the `submit-search` .

use this code.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" name="submit-search" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
```

Comment: You are still using submit-search inside type which is not correct.